# Finding elements in a HTML list based on another element in the list using Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

```
    <ul id="Group_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001" class="xxxxxxxxx">
        <li class="buttons">        
            <button class="button edit">Edit</button>
            <button class="button addToOption">Add to option</button>
            <button class="button removeFromOption" >Remove from option</button>
            <button class="button addToGroup">Add to group</button>
            <button class="button removeFromGroup">Remove from group</button>
        </li>
        <li class="content">
            <div class="text">
                <span id="Title_Of_The_Item" class="title"> QSE244</span>           
                <p class="description">A description about this item</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="Group_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002" class="xxxxxxxxx">
        <li class="buttons">        
            <button class="button edit">Edit</button>
            <button class="button addToOption">Add to option</button>
            <button class="button removeFromOption" >Remove from option</button>
            <button class="button addToGroup">Add to group</button>
            <button class="button removeFromGroup">Remove from group</button>
        </li>
        <li class="content">
            <div class="text">
                <span id="Title_Of_The_Item" class="title"> QSE236 </span>          
                <p class="description">A description about this item</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

In the structure above I want to be able to click on the any button listed based on the titles like the QSE244 or QSE236 - ie clicking the corrosponding buttons. There is no point in using the id's Group_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 as they ll be replaced with dynamic GUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only thing that differentiates these two blocks, and, presumably, many more like them, is the text of the `<span class="title">` element, that's what you need to key off of.  I'd try a locator something like this:

```
xpath=//ul[li[@class='content']/div/span[@class='title' and .='the_title_value']]/li[@class='buttons']/button[contains(@class, 'the_button_type']
```

which means "the button with class 'the_button_type' that is contained within the list with class 'buttons' which is contained within the unordered list that contains a list with class 'content' that contains a div that contains a span with class 'title' and the text 'the_title_value'.  So you use the title value to locate the correct ul element, and then you navigate to the button from there.